# Want to save values from a pop up to a jqgrid/table

Tags: java, jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

I have a requirement in which when a user click submit on pop up window the value should get saved into a cell of a  default grid on the page.How can I do this functionality?
Is it possible using jquery?Can any body provide me a working exmple please?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery UI dialog. There is a good example of it [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form). Basically it is all you need.

Comment: is there any other way what if i want to avoid jquery UI dialogs

Comment: Yes there are :) Do you have any example code? How do you want to make that popup window? I mean using what?

Comment: I want to open a pop using simple dialog box and than want the values to be get saved from a pop to a jqgrid cell on click of pop up submit button.